# Maven - deploy webapp to tomcat before JUnit test

Tags: maven, tomcat, junit, maven-2, tomcat7

I have webapp which provides web service. I want to perform JUnit tests with SoapUI to check if this service is working properly.
But to test web service application has to be deployed to my Tomcat 7 server.

I have no idea how to configure maven to build war, then deploy it to tomcat (ideally: to run separate tomcat instance for this) and then to run JUnit tests.
I will appreciate any help.

I am using maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There are a number of schools of thought as to how to handle this type of *integration test* with Maven.

I should point out that when you are deploying an application to an application server, you are not in the realm of unit testing any more. Because the entire application is being deployed within a container, you are testing the integration of those two components.

Now there is nothing wrong with using JUnit for running *integration tests* (though there are some limitations that you may hit, for example *unit tests* should not care about the sequencing of individual tests - assuming you are writing them correctly - so JUnit *enforces* this by not guaranteeing any sequence of execution... prior to Java 1.7 the execution order was accidentally implied by the order of test methods within a class, but it was not part of the JUnit contract... Some people switch to other testing frameworks for their *integration* tests, e.g. TestNG, if they find the *unit test focus* of JUnit is getting in the way of their test development)

The key point to keep in mind is that the Maven lifecycle uses the `test` phase for the execution of *unit* tests.

When it comes to *integration* tests there are two (and a half) schools of thought as to the right way to handle the tests with Maven.

## School 1 - Failsafe and `integration-test/verify`

This school of thought uses the phases after `package` to start up a container, run the integration tests, tear down the container, and finally check the test results and fail the build in the event of test failures.

*NEVER EVER RUN `mvn integration-test` as that will not tear down the container correctly, any time you think you want to type `mvn integration-test` you actually want to type `mvn verify` (oh look, it's shorter and easier to type also... bonus)*

So with this you do the following:

- Bind [tomcat7:run](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) to the `pre-integration-test` phase with [`fork`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#fork)`=true`
- Bind [failsafe:integration-test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) to the `integration-test` phase
- Bind [tomcat7:shutdown](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/shutdown-mojo.html) to the `post-integration-test` phase
- Bind failsafe:verify to the `verify` phase.

For extra brownie points you would use [build-helper-maven-plugin:reserve-network-port](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/reserve-network-port-mojo.html) bound to the `validate` phase to ensure that the test server is started on an unused network port and then either use resource filtering against the test resources to pass the port through to the tests or use a system property passed through [systemPropertyVariables](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#systemPropertyVariables) to make the port number available to the tests.

### Advantages

- Clean Maven build
- If the tests fail, you cannot release the project
- Can move the integration tests into a separate profile (by convention called `run-its`) if the tests are too slow to run every build.

### Disadvantages

- Hard to run the tests from an IDE. All the integration tests start/end in `IT` and while Maven knows to run tests starting/ending in `Test` with Surefire and run tests starting/ending in `IT` with Failsafe, your IDE probably doesn't. Additionally, your IDE is not going to start the container for you, so you have to do a lot of work by hand to actually run the tests manually.
- Debugging the tests potentially requires attaching two debuggers, e.g. one to debug the application running in container and the other to [debug the test cases](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#debugForkedProcess).

  ```
  mvnDebug -Dmaven.failsafe.debug=true verify
  ```
- Couples your tests to the Maven build process.

## School 2 - Separate module

This school of thought moves the integration tests into a separate module that depends on the `war` module and copies the `war` into the test resources using, e.g. [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) bound to the `generate-test-resources` phase coupled with a Tomcat7 dependency to test against.

The test cases themselves start up the Tomcat7 container using [embedded mode](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html)

### Advantages

- Tests can run in IDE
- Integration tests are separated from Unit tests, so asking the IDE to run all tests will not kick off the slower tests

### Disadvantages

- The `war` artifact is only rebuilt if you go past the `package` phase, consequently, you need to run at least `mvn clean package` periodically to refresh the code under test when using the IDE.
- The failure of the integration tests does not break the build of the `war` module, so you can end up releasing a broken `war` artifact and then have the reactor build fail for the integration test module. Some people counteract this issue by having the integration test module within `src/it` and using Maven Invoker Plugin to run the tests... though that provides a poorer IDE integration, so I do not recommend that line.
- Hard to get a consolidated test coverage report from Maven.
- Have to code the container start/stop yourself from within your test cases.

## School 2.5 - Failsafe with the test cases starting their own Tomcat7 server

This is a kind of hybrid of the two approaches.

You use Failsafe to execute the tests, but the tests themselves are responsible for starting and stopping the Tomcat7 container that you want to test in.

### Advantages

- Don't have to configure the server start/stop in Maven pom
- IDE can safely run all tests (though the integration tests may be slower and you may want to not run them, but it's not like they will all fail unless there is a test failure)
- Easier to debug the tests from your IDE (only one process to attach against, and the IDE usually makes it easy to debug tests by providing a special test runner)

### Disadvantages

- Have to code the container start/stop yourself from within your test cases

---

I hope the above helps you understand the options you have. There may be other tweaks but in general the above are considered the best practice(s) for integration testing with Maven at present.

Comment: This is beautiful response. Pity I can give only one upvote ;-)

Comment: +1 One of the best answers on SO I have seen in a while.

Comment: I really like your response. There's just one thing that I'm fuzzy on: where did you figure out the convention of naming the profile that'll run integration tests "run-its"?

Comment: Lots of projects use that profile name, so it has become the convention... Especially as it is the convention we use in the maven project itself

Comment: Failsafe and integration-test/verify plus Eclipse: in our case, we generally run our app servers locally from Eclipse, and use the annotation `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` on our integration tests, which seems to be enough for Eclipse to recognise our unit tests.

Comment: Is there a good example of how to implement "2.5"? The "disadvantage": Have to code the container start/stop yourself from within your test cases is exactly what I want to do but I can't find a guide showing how to do it.

Comment: https://github.com/mjeanroy/junit-servers looks like it might be an easy way to do this (I haven't used it myself, rather a 5 second google search revealed it) It has support for `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` use which means you don't need to extend from a specific test class (always a good thing to be able to use as a mix-in rather than enforcing class inheritance)

Answer (score 3):

@Stephen Connolly - your answer above was really good. I thought I'd kick in and show a full configuration for what you termed a `School 1` response.

This configuration:

- runs unit tests separately from integration tests. It uses the `@Category` annotation on the root classes that unit tests and integration tests extend.
- before integration tests it starts the dependent application (loaded as a maven dependency at runtime) on the local machine, by finding an open port
- after integration tests it tears down the dependent application

There's other stuff in there like how to set certain system properties on the dependent application only.

So far this configuration is working awesome..

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>reserve-network-port</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <portNames>
                            <portName>tomcat.maven.http.port</portName>
                        </portNames>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-local-ip</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>local-ip</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- if not given, 'local.ip' name is used -->
                        <localIpProperty>local.ip</localIpProperty>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- http port from reserve-network-port-plugin-->
                <port>${tomcat.maven.http.port}</port>
                <!-- application path always starts with /-->
                <path>/</path>
                <webapps>
                    <webapp>
                        <groupId>com.company.other.app</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web-rest</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <contextPath>/webapi-loopback</contextPath>
                        <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                    </webapp>
                </webapps>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-server</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <spring.profiles.active>test,h2</spring.profiles.active>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-server</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shutdown</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludedGroups>com.company.app.service.IntegrationTestRootClassAnnotatedWithAtCategory</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m @{jacocoArgLine}</argLine>
                        <excludedGroups> com.company.app.service.IntegrationTestRootClassAnnotatedWithAtCategory </excludedGroups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m @{jacocoArgLine}</argLine>
                        <groups>com.company.app.IntegrationTestRootClassAnnotatedWithAtCategory</groups>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <program.service.url>
                                http://${local.ip}:${tomcat.maven.http.port}/webapi-loopback
                            </program.service.url>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Connolly explains there is no a direct way to configure this. I will explain how to solve this using failsafe plugin. In the maven lifecycle type of test can be tested. Unit testing one of them and another one is integrate testing.  Unit testing can be run in the test stage of maven lifecycle. When you want to do integrate test it can be done in verify stage. If you want to know the difference between unit testing and integrate testing, this is a [good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752/what-is-the-difference-between-integration-and-unit-tests). By default unit test classes should be in **`***/*Test.java`**, and **`**/*TestCase.java`**  this format. The failsafe plugin will look for **`**/IT*.java`**, **`**/*IT.java`**, and **`**/*ITCase.java`**.

Here is an example. 
[image]

Here I have one unit test class and one integrate test class. Now I will explain, how should be the looks like maven pom.xml. Build section of maven configuration should look like this.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <warName>${name}</warName>
                <outputDirectory>/home/jobs/wso2/wso2as-5.3.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps</outputDirectory>
                <goal>
                </goal>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Unit tests are run before deploying the web app(war file). But integrate tests are run in  verify stage. I hope your requirement is satisfied in this stage.