# Integration testing with client server application in Maven multi-modules project

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jetty

I have a project composed of several modules that uses maven and is automatically uploaded and deployed to a Jenkins application that runs the build and its tests.

There is for example an API module, a server and a client.

Both client and server use the API as dependency to be able to work correctly.
The client connects to the server's web-services through HTTP(s) in normal use.

To be able to function, the server needs to be run on Jetty.

I have unit testing that works and test the client by calling the server's functionality with mocked HTTP requests.

I would like to be able to do some integration testing, to test for example the HTTP (and HTTPS) connection between the 2 entities, testing for timeouts and such, and reproducing the unit testing without resorting to mocked request, to be closer to real use cases.

It seems like such a thing should be easy to do, but I can't find a way to do it simply and in a way that could be automated.

For example, testing manually in my IDE is done by clicking on "run war" on the server project, and "run tests" on my application.

Is there a way to reproduce this simple process in Jenkins so it is done automatically, by Maven configuration or even a Jenkins plugin ?

**UPDATE :**

I'm trying to make another module that would use the war resulting from the packaging of my server, and run it with Jetty.
Since my server's Jetty configuration is quite complicated, using Spring and https configuration filtered by Maven, I've some problems making it work in my new module because of missing classes and relative paths not working in that context.

Is it possible to run that war like it would have been started in the other module without jumping through hoops of duplicating resources and other dirty tricks ?

For information, the specific Jetty war part of my pom.xml is :

```
<configuration>
                    <contextHandlers>
                        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <war>${project.parent.basedir}/cmp-service/cmp-webapp/target/cmp-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</war>
                            <contextPath>/cmp</contextPath>
                            <persistTempDirectory>true</persistTempDirectory>
                            <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                        </contextHandler>
                    </contextHandlers>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

I managed to build a functioning module that starts jetty and run my integration test with this pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.project.test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.test.integration-testing</groupId>

    <artifactId>integration-testing</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>integration-testing</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <contextHandlers>
                        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <war>
                                ${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/target/myservice-${project.parent.version}.war
                            </war>
                            <contextPath>/cmp</contextPath>
                            <persistTempDirectory>true</persistTempDirectory>
                            <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                        </contextHandler>
                    </contextHandlers>

                    <contextXml>
                        ${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/src/test/resources/jetty/jetty-context.xml
                    </contextXml>
                    <jettyXml>
                        ${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/src/test/resources/jetty/jetty.xml,${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/src/test/resources/jetty/jetty-ssl.xml,${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/src/test/resources/jetty/jetty-http.xml,${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/src/test/resources/jetty/jetty-https.xml
                    </jettyXml>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>scsf.configuration.file</name>
                            <value>
                                ${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/src/main/resources/config/cmpserver.properties
                            </value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait</name>
                            <value>180</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <systemPropertiesFile>
                        ${project.parent.basedir}/myserver/myservice/src/main/resources/config/cmpserver.properties
                    </systemPropertiesFile>
                    <daemon>true</daemon>

                    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>10001</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
       ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You need to add the dependency to your war as provided too.

But (there's always a but) there is a problem when running the verify goal.
When I run verify in my integration-test module, it kind of works.
But when I run the verify goal in the parent, which is supposed to call that exact same verify goal of my integration-test module (if I understand correctly how it works), some paths are treated differently and are resolved as, for example, parent/src/... instead of parent/integration-test/src...

It seems that when running my goal from the parent, the context of the execution changes and causes my application to break when looking for resources and such.

Is there something I didn't understand about how the whole process works and is there a way to make it work ?

### UPDATE 3

I've resolved to hack my way into making all my paths into absolute paths, it works, but it doesn't explain that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You already figured out the basic steps yourself:

- create a **separate module** for integration tests
- start an **application- or web-server** (e.g.jetty) via a suitable maven-plugin (e.g. [cargo](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html#Maven2plugin-gettingstarted), [wildfly-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/index.html), etc.) in the *pre-integration-test* phase
- **run tests** via the [`maven-failsafe-plugin:integration-test`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) mojo
- **verify results** via the [`maven-failsafe-plugin:verify`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html) mojo

Stephen Connolly, a maven developer, already wrote a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935290/maven-deploy-webapp-to-tomcat-before-junit-test/16936585#16936585) about this topic on stackoverflow.

I don't know the [jetty-maven-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) very well, but it seems it doesn't support deploying an existing artifact. Specifying relative or absolute path is definitively not the way to go here. You should probably use cargo instead to deploy to jetty. The cargo configuration could look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configuration>
    <type>runtime</type>
    <properties>
      <cargo.hostname>testserver</cargo.hostname>
      <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
  <container>
    <containerId>jetty9x</containerId>
  </container>
  <deployables>
    <deployable>
      <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>your-war</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
      <properties>
        <context>/cmp</context>
      </properties>
    </deployable>
  </deployables>
  <deployer>
    <type>remote</type>
  </deployer>
</configuration>
```

The [cargo documentation](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide.html) has more details.

hth,
- martin

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hello Jay,

Would really like to simplify things in here, why don't you run these jobs in succession? First would be your compile, unit-tests and deploy tasks using Maven. For your integration testing, create another job that would use of plugins like Selenium ( for your web application) and JMeter (for your web services). You can also try other license testing suite like Openscript.

The web service testing will be tricky, since your web service consumer runs on another client. Do you have any slave agents running on the client application? If you have one, run those jobs inside the slave.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that we're actually 4 working on the project and we all want to be able to run the tests locally, and on the integration testing platform that is Jenkins.
Also, thanks to a day browsing google and trying things, I managed to do something that kind of work but bring other problems. I'm updating my question