# How to use ServiceStack.GetAsync with ReactiveCommand (v6)

Tags: c#, servicestack, async-await, reactiveui

I'm trying to combine `ReactiveCommand` with [ServiceStack asynchronous API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#using-the-new-api).

The `x => _reactiveList.AddRange(x)` is never called and the test `res` is null. I don't now how to convert ServiceStack's `Task<TResponse> GetAsync<TResponse>(IReturn<TResponse> requestDto)` result into reactive `IObservable<T>`.

```
    public ReactiveCommand<IList<string>> ServiceReadCommand { get; protected set; }

    public ReactiveList<string> ReactiveList
    {
        get { return _reactiveList; }
        set { _reactiveList = this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _reactiveList, value); }
    }

    private ReactiveList<string> _reactiveList = new ReactiveList<string>();

    public TestViewModel(IScreen screen = null)
    {
        HostScreen = screen;

        ServiceReadCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(x => ServiceCommandTask(), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler);
        ServiceReadCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine((object)x));
        ServiceReadCommand.Subscribe(x => _reactiveList.AddRange(x));
    }

    private async Task<IList<string>> ServiceCommandTask()
    {
        this.Log().Info("Service command task");

        var baseUri = "http://localhost:9010";
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUri);

        // Works
        return await Observable.Return(new List<string> { "" });

        // Don't
        return await client.GetAsync(new TestRequest());
    }
```

And test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IList<string> res = null;
        new TestScheduler().With(sched =>
        {
            var viewModel = new TestViewModel();

            viewModel.ServiceReadCommand.CanExecute(null).Should().BeTrue();
            viewModel.ServiceReadCommand.ExecuteAsync(null).Subscribe(x => res = x);

            sched.AdvanceByMs(1000);

            return viewModel.ReactiveList;
        });

        res.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    }
```

---

I have added [console application](https://github.com/veraciousnottaken/Test.Rx.ServiceStack.git) with all code. Change `ServiceCommandTask` to `IObservable<T>` didn't helped. Adding `Thread.Sleep()` between

```
viewModel.ServiceReadCommand.ExecuteAsync(null).Subscribe(x => res = x);
//Thread.Sleep(1000);
sched.AdvanceByMs(1000);
```

resolves the issue but this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are a couple things that could be wrong. Everything looks like it should run, but you never know.

I do know that there are usually some weird things in ReactiveUI when dealing directly with Tasks and the `TestScheduler` though, so there are a couple of things that you could try on that front.

1. You could use the [`ToObservable()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229069%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to convert the `Task<TResponse>` into an `IObservable<TResponse>`.

   ```
   using System.Reactive.Linq;
   // ...
   return await (client.GetAsync(new TestRequest()).ToObservable());
   ```
2. The other idea has to do with forcing your `ServiceCommandTask()` method to return an `IObservable` and not use `async/await`. To do that you would have to change how you create your `ReactiveCommand` to use `ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable` and you would just use [`ToObservable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229069%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in `ServiceCommandTask()` on the `Task` that is returned from the ServiceStack call.

The reason why converting the `Task` into an `IObservable` might work is because the `TestScheduler` relies on virtual time to wait for things to happen. The `TestSchedluer` cannot interact properly with the `Task` and therefore when it "skips" ahead 1 second no time has actually passed in the real world. If the ServiceStack call does not return instantly then I would expect that to be the case and that problem may or may not be fixable by the above solutions.

Comment: I think it's timing problem but I don't know how to resolve it. Sample code on GitHub

Comment: @Tomasito Yeah, I think your biggest problem is that you are [actually writing an integration test, not a unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752/what-is-the-difference-between-integration-and-unit-tests). It is an integration test because it uses your ServiceStack dependency instead of mocking it. Because you are trying to perform an operation that takes *real* time, `AdvanceByMs(1000)` will not help you out at all. You instead have to wait for *real* time, which means that you have to use `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000)` works only in `Main(string[] args)`, when in `TestMethod1` it gives me `ServiceStack.WebServiceException: Method Not Allowed` exception. Last executed method is `System.Reactive.ScheduledObserver`1.Run(Object state, Action`1 recurse)`. Is my all architecture wrong? I mean calling service from ReactiveCommand?

Comment: @Tomasito I would say that calling ServiceStack from your reactive command **when you are unit testing** is bad because then you are trying to test ServiceStack as well as your ReactiveCommand at the same time. I would move your `GetAsync` method into an interface that you could mock (i.e. replace with a dummy version) inside your unit test so that the only functionality you are testing is your ReactiveCommand functionality. If you need to test whether ServiceStack works then you should make a different unit test for that.

Comment: I need at least one test to make sure they are working together. True?

Comment: @Tomasito Actually, no. If you have a test to make sure that your ReactiveCommand is working as expected and you have a test to make sure that ServiceStack is working as expected then you know for a fact that they will work together. That is the logic that [Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) is based upon. [Check out this answer to see what I mean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7876055/1832856)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right on the ReactiveUI end, something's going on with ServiceStack.