# How to unit test a data extraction method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have created a method which interacts with a framework, pulling out order items which have a completed status.

However, how can I unit test my method to ensure it behaves correctly...

```
class A
{
    public function extractData()
    {
        // extract data from framework
        $dataCollection = FrameworkX->getDataCollection('sales/orders');
        $dataCollection->filter('state', 'complete');

        return $extractedData;
    }
}


ClassATest
{
    public function test_extracted_data_contains_only_items_with_complete_status {
        $sut  = new ClassA();
        $sut->extractData();

        // What is the assertion here?
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not the unit-test, but the Integration test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the collection and assert that every item is in 'Complete' state.

However what you're doing here is called an [integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752/what-is-the-difference-between-integration-and-unit-tests).

You're not testing your method (unit), but you test how the framework behave (get's the data from the storage) and how the filter method works.

If you want to have a Unit-Test have a look at this [article](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html). You should create a Stub for your `FramewokX->getDataCollection()` method.

**How to test methods with third party dependencies**

If the FrameworkX is final then you can declare an interface:

```
interface iDataSource
{
    public function getDataCollection($path);
}
```

and a new class:

```
class DataSource implements iDataSource
   {
      public function getDataCollection($path)
      {
         //no need to test this method, it's just a wrapper
         return  FrameworkX->getDataCollection('sales/orders');
      }
    }
```

In your class A create [a constructor](http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern):

```
public function __construct(iDataSource $dataSource)
 {
   $this->dataSource= $dataSource;
 }
```

And change the `extractData` method to use it.

```
public function extractData()
{
    // extract data from framework
    $dataCollection = $dataSource->getDataCollection('sales/orders');
    $dataCollection->filter('state', 'complete');

    return $extractedData;
}
```

Let's assume that you're using PHPUnit.

```
 public function test_extracted_data_contains_only_items_with_complete_status ()
 {
    // Create a stub for the DataSource class.
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('DataSource')
                 ->getMock();

    // Configure the stub.
    $stub->method('getDataCollection')
         ->willReturn(preconfigured_collection_with_all_statuses_here);

    $sut  = new ClassA($stub); //create a new constructor and pass the stub
    $sut->extractData();
    // and after that verify that your method filtered out non complete statuses
 }
```

Comment: So the extractData method cannot be unit tested?  If working in a tdd method, how would you progress through this?

Comment: Unfortunately the FrameworkX class is final so this would not work

Comment: It's not a problem, you can declare your own wrapper for it.

Comment: @MartyWallace I've updated my answer. Have a look please.