# Mock a method for test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Trying to mock a method that is called within another method.

```
// code part
public virtual bool hello(string name, int age)
{
    string lastName = GetLastName();
}

public virtual string GetLastName() 
{
    return "xxx"; 
}

// unit test part
Mock<Program> p = new Mock<Program>();
p.Setup(x => x.GetLastName()).Returns("qqq");
```

I want the method GetLastName to always return "qqq".

Comment: what problem are you having with what you've tried?  that looks correct

Comment: The value of my last name is still = xxx when I put breakpoints in. Also failing the unit test

Comment: what to do if you only want to mock base.xmethod() which is call inside extended xmethod class

Answer (score 30):

This should work, assuming those are the full method implementations

```
public class MyProgram
{

    public bool hello(string name, int age)
    {
        string lastName = GetLastName();

        return string.Format("hello {0}", lastName);
    }

    public virtual string GetLastName() 
    {
        return "xxx"; 
    }
}

public class MyProgramTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {

        string stringToReturn = "qqq";
        Mock<MyProgram> name = new Mock<MyProgram>();
        name.CallBase = true;
        name.Setup(x => x.GetLastName()).Returns(stringToReturn );

        var results = name.Object.hello(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>());

        string expected = string.Format("hello {0}", results);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, results);
    }
}
```

I'm still not quite following your comment:

> What does the parameter really mean of Mock What should ?? be? excuse me, I don't quite understand the syntax. To clarify, mock means that when I put break points in my code I the breakpoints should skip the methods that I am mocking. Am I right?

`Mock<T>`  allows you to mock a type of `T` - `T` being a generic indicator, also meaning pretty much anything that's a class.  In the traditional, you would be mocking an `interface`, not an actual `class`, but in the example above, we're mocking a class.  For the sample unit test posted, the purpose of the unit test is to test the implementation of `hello(string, int)`.  We know that `hello(string, int)` relies on another method within that class called `GetLastName()`.  `GetLastName()`s implementation, while important, is not important to the scope of unit testing `hello(string, int)`.  For this reason, we mock the call and its return - in order to test the functionality of `hello(string, int)` without having to worry about its dependency's implementation.

I have surrounded the above with actual class names to hopefully make it more obvious that we're mocking the class `MyProgram` and providing a new implementation (mock) of `GetLastName()`

> Thanks for the answer. What if I want to test a method that calls another method that calls another method? For eg. what if the method hello called another method?

The same principle applies, when you're building your unit tests (assuming they are ***unit*** tests, and not integration tests or other, you always want to concentrate on testing ***one*** public method.  [What's the difference between unit and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876055/2312877)

```
public class Foo
{

    public string Bar()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}Bar", Baz(5));;
    }

    public virtual string Baz(int someNumber)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}Baz", DoStuff(someNumber).ToString());
    }

    public virtual int DoStuff(int someNumber)
    {
        return someNumber+1;
    }

}
```

If we're unit testing `Bar()` we do not care about the implementation of `Baz(int)` or even worse `DoStuff(int)`.  Note ***we don't care about the implementation***, we ***do*** care that they return values.  From `Bar()`s perspective, the only thing that is important is the `Baz(int)` returns a string.  What string?  It doesn't matter to `Bar()`s unit test.

Sample test for `Bar()`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Bar_ReturnsBazValueWithBarAppended
{
    // Arrange
    string testBazReturn = "test";
    Mock<Foo> mock = new Mock<Foo>();
    mock.CallBase = true;
    mock
        .Setup(s => s.Baz(It.IsAny<int>())
        .Returns(testBazReturn);

    // Act
    var results = mock.Object.Bar();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("{0}{1}", testBazReturn, "Bar"), results);
    mock.Verify(v => v.Baz(It.IsAny<int>())); // Verifies that Baz was called
}
```

Notice in the above, our actual implementations of `Baz(int)`, and `DoStuff(int)` do not matter, as we are disregarding the actual implementation of `Baz(int)`, and `DoStuff(int)` doesn't even come into play.

Now, if we were to test `Baz(int)` we just follow the same mentality:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Baz_ReturnsDoStuffValueWithBazAppended
{
    // Arrange
    int testDoStuffReturn = 1;
    Mock<Foo> mock = new Mock<Foo>();
    mock.CallBase = true;
    mock
        .Setup(s => s.DoStuff(It.IsAny<int>())
        .Returns(testDoStuffReturn);

    // Act
    var results = mock.Object.Baz(5);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("{0}{1}", results, "Baz"), results); // Validates the result
    mock.Verify(v => v.DoStuff(It.IsAny<int>())); // Verifies that DoStuff was called
}
```

In the above, now that we're unit testing `Baz(int)`, we don't care about `Bar()`, and the only thing we care about in `DoStuff(int)` is that it returns a value (but not ***how*** it arrives at that value.)

And finally `DoStuff(int)`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoStuff_ReturnsParameterPlusOne()
{
    // Arrange
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    int passed = 1;
    int expected = passed + 1;

    // Act
    var results = foo.DoStuff(passed);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, results);
}
```

Comment: should I use the base or extended class or does that not matter for program? (parameter in Mock)

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you elaborate in the question with samples of what you mean?

Comment: What does the parameter really mean of Mock<??> What should ?? be? excuse me, I don't quite understand the syntax. To clarify, mock means that when I put break points in my code I the breakpoints should skip the methods that I am mocking. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I want to test a method that calls another method that calls another method? For eg. what if the method hello called another method?

Comment: By using virtual just for the sake of mocking a method you're adopting hazardous code smells. Using an interface here would be safer.

Comment: @Kritner This was an excellent explanation and helped me apply it to a problem I was having at work. Thanks much!

Comment: what to do if you only want to mock base.xmethod() which is call inside extended xmethod class

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `.CallBase()` extension method that allows you to control whether the original method is called for each individual method which can be more useful:

```
name.Setup(x => x.hello()).CallBase();
```