# How to test a method that runs an SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot, minitest

I've made a custom SQL query and I want to create a unit tests to demonstrate that it works. I have tested it in SQLDeveloper and it works as I want it to on my test database but I want to leave a unit test for those who have to maintain this code later.

```
def report_of_merchants_who_have_not_pressed_the_service_rendered_button
    sql = "SELECT MIN(departure_date), ch_invoice.invoice_id
    FROM ch_invoice
    INNER JOIN ch_trip
    ON ch_invoice.invoice_id = ch_trip.invoice_id
    WHERE departure_date < SYSDATE
    AND service_rendered = 0
    AND paid = 1
    Group By ch_invoice.invoice_id"

    report = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
    render json: report
  end
```

My thought was to create four invoices, three of which are not meeting the above criteria and one that does. Where I am getting stuck is how to check that the query only returns back one response. How do I test that one row of the query is coming out?

**Clarification**
I was intending on creating these invoices & trips with FactoryGirl to fill the models. Will that still work?

Comment: In general, unit tests should not depend on outside services. A typical unit test would mock the response from the test database and test that processing the returned data is done properly. The reason is that once you write a unit test that depends on that database, the unit tests will have to be changed every time you change your database implementation. That isn't really a unit test, it's an integration test. TLDR: You can do this, but it is a bad idea. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752/what-is-the-difference-between-integration-and-unit-tests

Comment: I don't see why unit tests can't talk to a database. Changing the db implementation is not really an issue because it is not likely to happen and if it does then this test would be thrown away with the database.

Comment: @BSeven Because when unit tests start talking to external services, they aren't unit tests by definition. They are integration tests, which should be maintained separately.

Comment: I guess if you think of the DB as an external service, then this would be an integration test.

Comment: Yes, FactoryGirl is a good way to generate the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this method in a class.

```
class MerchantReport
  class << self
    def for_not_pressed_the_service_rendered_button
      sql = "SELECT MIN(departure_date), ch_invoice.invoice_id
      ....    
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
    end
```

In your test,

```
report = MerchantReport.for_not_pressed_the_service_rendered_button
```

FWIW, I don't think queries like reports have anything to do with Invoices or other models, and belong in their own class.

Yes, you can create 4 invoices in your setup. Also, you can create a separate test for each condition that you want to test. For example, you can have one test for date (`departure_date < SYSDATE`). That may be more readable than having one test for all conditions.

Comment: Then a test like assertion like `assert_equal 1, report.count` ?

Comment: I would also test for the specific record: `assert_equal valid_invoice, report.first`.